# How to make a selection black and white, no grey?

Tags: gimp

I read that with *Image ⇾ Mode ⇾ Indexed*  I can get the whole image black and white without grey, but how to only apply this to a selection, other than copy the selection out – apply – paste back?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Unfortunately it's not possible using Indexed colour. You can't use it on a selection only.  Indexed colour is a colour mode, not just an effect. Colour modes apply to the whole document. Try using *Colours > Threshold* instead, or maybe a combination of *Desaturate*, then *Threshold*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a selection and use the Threshold tool on it:

[image]

Note that when doing so you have no fine control on which colors become black and which become white, so a more complete solution is to convert to monochrome first (`Colors ➤ Desaturate ➤ Desaturate` or `Colors ➤ Desaturate ➤ Mono mixer`) before applying the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [G'MIC Filters](https://gmic.eu/) that come as a plugin for Gimp. These filters are applied to a selection if there is one. Below is using the filter *Black & White > Stamp*:

[image]